# map static files to alternate path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

So I have a MVC website at this location on disk: `C:\MyApp\Applications\1.0.0.0`, however I have static resources in a shared location like: `C:\OtherApps\myapp\css\site.css`

How can I intercept requests for static files to my MVC app and map the path to this alternate resources location? I have an `IHttpHandler` that I can apply to specific paths, but I want to do this for all static files (things that don't match an MVC route).

note: nothing is serving resources from the alternate location, so a rewrite will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to instruct ASP.NET to handle all requests by adding this to your modules section:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
```

then put in a handler that will handle everything (after all your other handlers):

```
<add name="static-files" verb="GET" path="*" type="MyApp.HttpHandlers.FileHttpHandler, MyApp"/>
```

there is a slight performance penalty for having ASP.NET process everything, including static files, but it's necessary for our site, and most things will get retrieved from the CDN anyway.